# What is the ?: syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

what does it mean for the following line?

```
T = ($("#a .b").hasClass("active") ? "C" : "D") ;
```

`$("#a .b").hasClass("active")` means whether `#a .b` exists? but how about `? "C" : "D"`, is it some kind of comparison logic?

Comment: It's the ternary operator (has nothing to do with jQuery) and is shorthand for an if/else statement

Comment: You are correct, I just saw it in a jquery statement. Thanks Roy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

If condition is true then expr1 would return else expr2 will return.

So, in your case:

```
T = ($("#a .b").hasClass("active") ? "C" : "D") ;
```

`T` variable will hold `"C"` if `$("#a .b")` has class `active` else it would hold `"D"`

Answer (score 1):

It tell you that :

```
if ( $("#a .b").hasClass("active") ) {    
   T = "C";
} else {
   T = "D"
}
```

Here you can read this doc for further understanding. [Ternary Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx)